# TypeORM & NestJS: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'joinColumns')

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I have a product entity and category entity. Product has a many to one relation to category and category has one too many with the product. When I try to load related products of a category I get an error.

I have a business product category entity as below:

```js
import { Entity, Column, ManyToOne, OneToMany, JoinColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { BaseEntity } from './base';
import { BusinessProductsEntity } from './product.entity';

@Entity('business_product_category')
export class BusinessProductCategoryEntity extends BaseEntity {
  @Column('varchar', { length: 50 })
  public category: string;

  @Column('text', { nullable: true })
  public description: string;

  @OneToMany(
    () => BusinessProductCategoryEntity,
    products => products.category,
  )
  products: BusinessProductsEntity[];
}
```

And a business product entity as:

```js
import { Entity, Column } from 'typeorm';
import { BaseEntity } from './base';

@Entity('business_products')
export class BusinessProductsEntity extends BaseEntity {
  @Column('jsonb', { nullable: true })
  public details: any;

  @Column('text', { nullable: true, name: 'additional_information' })
  public additionalInformation: string;

  @Column('int', { default: 0, name: 'total_stock' })
  public totalStock: number;

  @Column('bigint', { default: 0 })
  public price: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => BusinessProductCategoryEntity, { eager: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'business_product_category_id' })
  public category: BusinessProductCategoryEntity;
}
```

When I try to `leftJoin` and load all products of a category I get the error:
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'joinColumns')`

The code I am using to load the relation:

```js
// doesn't work
this.categoryRepository.find({ relations: ['products'] });

// doesn't work either
this.categoryRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('category')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('category.products', 'products')
      .getMany();
```

Comment: [docs here](https://typeorm.io/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations) suggest that you can omit @JoinColumn in O2M and M2O relations.  Leaving it might be having some adverse effect (maybe you have it to explicitly specify the column name if non-default)

Answer (score 2):

I faced this error after updating the `Entity` file, we solved it with delete the `dist` folder and running my project again

Answer (score 1):

As per the [document](http://typeorm-doc.exceptionfound.com/classes/relationjoincolumnbuilder.html) when join column is set with custom name and without referenced column name we need automatically set referenced column name - primary ids by default. As there is no primary column mentioned in the `business_product_category` entity, add a `referencedColumnName` in `@JoinColumn` as such:

```
 @ManyToOne(() => BusinessProductCategoryEntity, { eager: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'business_product_category_id', referencedColumnName:"// your intended column name" })
  public category: BusinessProductCategoryEntity;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall dependencies by deleting `node_modules` and running `npm cache clean --force` before. Also check your node version to be the latest. These actions helped me with a similar issue.